# Filter in power bi with an external list

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a filter in power bi, but instead of a pre defined list, i want a field where the user can input a list (from an excel, for exemple) using copy-paste.

Is that possible?

I've already tried to use an excel in sharepoint, but the user do not have authorization to update the dashboard whenever he's using the dashboard

Comment: No this is not possible. The use case seems strange, why not use the data in the table you are trying to use to drive that list? You are entering data, to filter on that may or may not be there. If you can expand on your use case we maybe able to give you some options

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can.

In this example I'm using a GoogleSheet spreadsheet that you can share with your mates. Connect Power BI to it and if you add fields they will be added to Power BI after every refresh:

[image]

Setup an automatic refresh every 10 minutes and I think you are done.